# Get Touch Points in ManipulationDelta event in UWP / Windows 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

In WPF4 MultiTouch, the UIElement.ManipulationDelta event reports the touch points via the [ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.Manipulators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationdeltaeventargs.manipulators(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

> // WPF4
>   // Gets a collection of objects that represents the touch contacts for the manipulation.
>   public IEnumerable Manipulators { get; }

Unfortunately there is no such property in UWP / Windows 10 Universal. [ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationdeltaroutedeventargs) contains only Cumulative and Delta manipulations (transforms) but not the actual touch points.

How can I get access to the raw touch points during a [UIElement.ManipulationDelta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationDelta) event?

Comment: I have found  the `Position` property in the `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs` class. And I tried to print `e.Position.X` and `e.Position.Y`, I found the output is exactly the coordinate location of the control relative to the touching point. Is that property you expect?

Comment: As far as Im aware, Position is an equivalent of WPF's `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.ManipulationOrigin` -- i.e. the center position of touch points when two or three touch points are on the screen. WPF's `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs` contains both `ManipulationOrigin` and `Manipulators` - individual touch points with positions